# Error sumando en función recursiva

Tags: java, array

El código es un arreglo que recibe cualquier conjunto de números (ejemplo, los numeros 10,7,8,23,9,2) y retorna la suma de los numeros primos, es con recursividad y en lenguaje Java

Lo qué pasa con este código es que me toma el 10 como primo y sé que no es primo. Como tal el problema siento que es el caso base y más bien no sé cómo expresar que no me tome el primer dígito ósea truena y no se que mas hacer. Gracias!

```
public class Primos {

public static int SumaArreglo(int a[]) {
    return SumaArreglo(a, a.length - 1);
}

public static int SumaArreglo(int a[], int i) {
    if (i == 0)
    {
    return a[0];
    }
     else if (Primo(a[i]) == true) {
        return a[i] + SumaArreglo(a, i - 1);
    } else {
        return SumaArreglo(a, i - 1);
    }
}

public static boolean Primo(int n, int contador) {

    if (contador == 1) {
        return true;
    } else if (n % contador == 0) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return Primo(n, contador - 1);
    }
}

public static boolean Primo(int n) {
    if (n == 1) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return Primo(n, n / 2);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int A[] = {10,7,8,23,9,2};
    showMessageDialog(null, SumaArreglo(A));
}
}
```

Comment: Cuál es tu problema? Este no es un lugar para revisarte el código o hacer tus deberes. Se trata de que traigas un problema que tengas con tu código para que te ayudemos a resolverlo.

Comment: Lo qué pasa es que me toma el 10 como primo y no es primo como tal el problema siento que es el caso base y más bien no sé cómo expresar que no me tome el primer dígito ósea truena y no se que mas hacer...

Comment: Debe de funcionar con cualquier conjunto de numeros

Comment: Por favor, usa la opción editar y editas tu pregunta para añadir información. Esta vez te ayudé.

Comment: Listo gracias :)

Comment: Para cuando i == 0, devuelves el primer elemento del array, que es 10. ¿Seguro que quieres hacer eso?

Comment: no , pues deberia de ser que primero me diga si es primo o no , si i en la posicion 0 es primo pues me retorna ese numero, si no no me retorna nada

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El lío con el 10 está en lo que haces cuando i es cero. Igual debes validar que sea primo, diría yo.

El código como lo probé quedaría así:

```
public class Primos {

    public static int SumaArreglo(int a[]) {
        return SumaArreglo(a, a.length - 1);
    }

    public static int SumaArreglo(int a[], int i) {
        if (i == 0)
        {
            return Primo(a[i]) ? a[i] : 0;
        }
        else if (Primo(a[i])) {
            return a[i] + SumaArreglo(a, i - 1);
        } else {
            return SumaArreglo(a, i - 1);
        }
    }

    public static boolean Primo(int n, int contador) {

        if (contador == 1) {
            return true;
        } else if (n % contador == 0) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return Primo(n, contador - 1);
        }
    }

    public static boolean Primo(int n) {
        if (n == 1) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return Primo(n, n / 2);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int A[] = {10,7,8,23,9,2};
        showMessageDialog(null, SumaArreglo(A));
    }
}
```

Comment: dejame checarlo amigo ... solamente una duda, que es el signo de interrogacion   return Primo(a[0]) ? a[0] : 0; por favor!!

Comment: Se llama operador ternario. Se evalúa lógicamente lo que está a la izquierda del signo de interrogación: si es verdadero, se retorna lo que está a la derecha; si es falso, se retorna lo que está tras los dos puntos.

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo de verdad!! Te lo agradezco